# What is the correct representation for discrete time sequence?

Tags: dft, periodic

I am bit confused after reading Frequency-Domain Sampling and Reconstruction of Discrete-Time Signals section from Proakis where, $$x(n)=\begin{cases}
               x_p(n),\;\;\;\;0\leq n \leq N-1\\
                     \\
               0,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;     \mathrm{elsewhere}\\
            \end{cases}$$
It is clear $x(n)$ is discrete time sequence but why $n$ is defined as $0 \leq n \leq N-1$ instead of $n=0,1,\dots,N-1$

Comment: Aren't those equivalents in this case? $N$ is an integer value.

Comment: Yes they are. Since $n$ is integer the sequence $x(n)$ run from $0$ to $N-1$

Comment: $N$ can be integer, but $n$ must be integer.

Comment: It's assumed (if not explicitly stated) that both $N$ and $n$ are integers.